# Trazer domínio externo (Registro br) para Azure

Tags: microsoft-azure, back-end, microsoft

Sou novo nesta questão então vai:
É o seguinte, tenho um domínio já adquirido no registro br, exemplo.com.br (é um exemplo). Realizei todo o processo de de sincronização com o git no azure.
Gostaria que a partir deste momento, meu servidor do site, fosse o Azure. Eu ainda preciso ter uma conta num host, tipo, hostinger ou goDaddy? Ou é possível que seja tudo feito no Azure mesmo? Se for possível, tem algum tutorial?

Um erro que aparece:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O Azure possui o serviço de DNS interno dele. Muito rápido e fácil de configurar. [Veja aqui como configurar seu DNS no Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/services/dns/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolvida da seguinte maneira:
No Registro br, crie um DNS do proprio registro br em editar zona, com o IP que se encontra no azure, registre-o, sendo ele do tipo A.

Feito isso, deverá aguardar até a propagação deste e então configurar o azure.